# Induced representation -- Exercise 3.16 Fulton Harris

Tags: representation-theory

We assume representations to be over the complex numbers.

Exercise 3.16 basically states: Let $G$ be a finite group and $H\leq G$. Prove that if $U$ is a representation of $G$ and $W$ of $H$, then:
$$U \otimes Ind(W) = Ind(Res(U) \otimes W)$$

My attempt:
\begin{align*} \varphi: Ind(Res(U) \otimes W) \to& U \otimes Ind(W) \\\\
  \sum_{gH \in G/H} g \cdot (u_g \otimes w_g) \to &  \left( \sum_{gH \in G/H} gu_g \right) \otimes \left( \sum_{gH \in G/H} g w_g\right)\end{align*}

However, how do I prove $\varphi$ is linear and an isomorphism? It seems to me like we have extra terms on the right, so surely it can't be an isomorphism...

Comment: $g \cdot (u_g \otimes w_g) = gu_g \otimes w_g = u_g \otimes gw_g$, it does not distribute to both elements. So your map should be $\sum_{gH \in G / H} g(u_g \otimes w_g) \rightarrow (\sum_{gH \in G/H} gu_g) \otimes (\sum_{gH \in G/H} w_g)$. See if this helps.

Comment: @popping900 that's not the standard definition of the tensor product of representations, OP is correct (except it has one too many $\sum_{gH\in G/H}$). Your definition of tensor products is not well-defined (consider the example $1\otimes\mathrm{sgn}$, where $1$ and $\mathrm{sgn}$ are characters of $S_2$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a natural choice of such a homomorphism $\varphi$. By adjunction, giving a $G$-homomorphism $Ind(Res(U)\otimes W)\to U\otimes Ind(W)$ is equivalent to giving a $H$-homomorphism $Res(U)\otimes W\to Res(U\otimes Ind(W))=Res(U)\otimes Res(Ind(W))$. So it suffices to give a $H$-homomorphism $W\to Res(Ind(W))$, which is the obvious map $w\mapsto w$.

Thus, our $H$-homomorphism is
$$\begin{align*}Res(U)\otimes W&\to Res(U\otimes Ind(W))\\
u\otimes w&\mapsto u\otimes w,\end{align*}$$
which by adjunction becomes the $G$-homomorphism
$$\begin{align*}\varphi\colon Ind(Res(U)\otimes W)&\to U\otimes Ind(W)\\
g.(u\otimes w)&\mapsto gu\otimes gw,\end{align*}$$
which linearly extends to $\sum_{g\in G}g(u_g\otimes w_g)\mapsto \sum_{g\in G}gu_g\otimes gw_g$.

**To check it's an isomorphism:** it suffices to check surjectivity, since the dimensions match. Since $Ind(W)$ is spanned by $\{gw:g\in G,w\in W\}$, the tensor product $U\otimes Ind(W)$ is spanned by $\{u\otimes gw:g\in G,u\in U,w\in W\}$. Thus, it suffices to check, for each $g\in G$, $u\in U$, and $w\in W$, the element $u\otimes gw$ is in the image of $\varphi$. But $\varphi(g.(g^{-1}u\otimes w))=u\otimes gw$, so this is OK.

Comment: I'm sorry for the question, this book was basically my first exposure to tensor products, and I'm not very familiar with arguments for surjectivity onto these spaces.

Is it enough to show that we can extend that application with $\pi_1: U \otimes Ind(W) \to U$ and with $\pi_2: U \otimes Ind(W) \to Ind(W)$ (both linear) and show that both these compositions with your application are surjective, and thus your application is surjective to $U \otimes Ind(W)$?

Comment: In other words, can I prove your mapping is surjective (I'll call it $\varphi$), by proving $(\pi_ 1 \circ \varphi)$ and $(\pi_2 \circ \varphi)$ are both surjective? Because I didn't really understand your argument that $\varphi$ is surjective.

Comment: @TC159 I updated the last paragraph of my answer to address your concerns.

Answer (score 1):

If you are particularly categorically minded here is a proof using lots of adjunctions:

$Hom_G(U \otimes Ind(W), -)$

$\cong Hom_G(Ind(W), U^*\otimes -)$

$\cong Hom_H(W, Res(U^* \otimes -))$

$\cong Hom_H(W, Res(U^*) \otimes Res(-))$

$\cong Hom_H(Res(U)\otimes W), Res(-))$

$Hom_G(Ind(Res(U)\otimes W), - )$

So by the Yoneda lemma $U \otimes Ind(W) \cong Ind(Res(U)\otimes W)$.

Comment: I am not, most of the proofs I had seen before used category theory, I do not know what an adjunction is so they are very inaccessible, at the moment I just want to keep studying group representation theory, thank you anyway for your answer. When I start studying category theory I will look at your proof again.

This proof also seems to have a lot of intermediary results that I have never seen before, (what I think is called Frobenius Reciprocity, which is soon to follow on the book I'm reading).

Comment: That's a good attitude to have. Category theory can be a great framework, but it's probably best to learn some other stuff first. Here are the representation theory facts used in that proof:

$$Hom_G(Ind(A),B) \cong Hom_H(A, Res(B))$$

$$Hom_G(A \otimes B, C) \cong Hom_G(B, A^* \otimes C)$$

$$Res(A \otimes B) \cong Res(A) \otimes Res(B)$$

$$Res(A^*) = Res(A)^*$$

The first one is indeed Frobenius reciprocity, the others don't really have names but they are basic properties of how duals and tensor products work for group representations.